# Uninstalling Software Built from Source

Tags: make

How can you uninstall software that was built and installed from source? (Using `make install`?)

Comment: The easy way would be to compile PHP 5.5 and install it over 5.4. The RPM likely installs to a different folder.

Comment: If you haven't already deleted the directory where you built from source, and if you let `make install` choose the target directory, it might have ended up in `/usr/local/bin`, which usually has precedence over `/usr/bin`, hence you still use the first `php` binary found in your `PATH`. You could try `make -n install` and see where and what it wants to install stuff, and remove by hand. Untested and dangerous, of course.

Comment: @dawud Yes, i actually ended up doing it this way.  I was just wondering if for future reference there might be a better, safer way

Comment: If the `Makefile` provides the means, then yes. Always generate packages, even for upstream built sources.

Comment: I don't understand the off-topic votes. I've had to do this more than a few times myself but had to figure it out the hard way.

Comment: OP, I blew away your question as it was asked to make it trigger less votes to close. It was a legitimate question masked behind a lot of extra words..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you still have the source package? You can parse the Makefile for install commands, or you can install it again (with another `$PREFIX`) to capture a list of installed files. Also, it is printed to STDOUT. You could then remove those files from the directory where they were installed originally.

**Edit:**

I just dug up my notes on making an uninstaller script. Bear with me, I am paraphrasing here.

After you build and install to a temporary target directory, do the following. (Where `$PREFIX` is whatever you used with `./configure`.)

```
cd $PREFIX
find . -type f | cut -b 1 --complement | sed 's/^/rm -f \/usr\/local/g' > uninstall.sh
find . -type d | cut -b 1 --complement | sed 's/^/rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty \/usr\/local/g' >> uninstall.sh
```

The output will look like:

```
rm -f /usr/local/lib/somelib.so
rm -f /usr/local/bin/somebin
rm -f /usr/local/include/someapp/someheaders.h
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty /usr/local/share
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty /usr/local/bin
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty /usr/local/include/someapp
...
```

This doesn't actually remove the critical system directories (`/usr/local/bin`, etc) because they'll be non-empty. Also, you'll want to confirm that your `./configure` script uses `/usr/local` as the default `$PREFIX`. Adjust the `sed` command as necessary.

Comment: Damn Linux. I really should start using a different prefix for each program isntead of /usr/local

Answer (score 3):

I checked with php version 5.4.16

```
cd php-5.4.16

make clean
make clean all

find / -name php

rm -fr /usr/local/php /usr/local/lib/php /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/include/php

whereis {php-config,phpize,php-cgi}
rm /usr/local/bin/php-config /usr/local/bin/phpize /usr/local/bin/php-cgi

whereis {pear,peardev}
rm /usr/local/bin/pear

rm /usr/local/bin/peardev


why I select phpize and php-config
because after ./configure I got this output

config.status: creating php5.spec
config.status: creating main/build-defs.h
config.status: creating scripts/phpize
config.status: creating scripts/man1/phpize.1
config.status: creating scripts/php-config
config.status: creating scripts/man1/php-config.1
config.status: creating sapi/cli/php.1
config.status: creating main/php_config.h
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to brute force it:

Do a `find / > /tmp/all_files` and save to a file `all_files`. (Exclude sysfs and procfs and other if you know the files are not there)

Do a `rpm -qa | xargs rpm -al > /tmp/all_owned_files` to get a list of all files "owned" by rpm. (Assuming this is a rpm based system, use other commands for non-rpm systems)

Do a diff between these two files, and comb through it.

Answer (score -1):

check the command in source directory

> make clean
>
> make clean all

Or you have to remove all the files as described by Aaron

Comment: `make clean` very rarely, in my experience, removes the installed binaries; it only cleans out compilation-related cruft from the build directory.

Comment: `make clean` in fact does not removed installed files. It simply removes things like object files (.o) so they can be re-compiled (say, if the configure or Makefile is changed).

Comment: I am just downloading the php source code to check what steps should be followed.